# React Native - how to save a base64 string as a NAMED file using the native Share.share

Tags: react-native

I am struggling saving a base64 string (a downloaded pdf) to a 'named' file, as in, I want to name this file 'statement 1' for instance.

```
Share.share({
  url: base64data,
  title: 'statement 1',
  message: 'statement 1',
});
```

This now shows the following:

[image]

YEAH - so far so good...

Now I hit 'Save to Files'

and this appears:

[image]

Strangly it shows **2 Items** to be saved and when I 'Save' it saves it like this:

[image]

The PDF document is the correct document and the text file actually contains the name of the file.

Not ideal.   How can I simply save this PDF with the name 'statement 1'?

Seems such a simple thing but I am stuck...

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try to use API without `message` and `title` parameters like below. Providing `message` property causes to create a `.txt` file. User can rename the pdf file once dialog pops up.

```
    Share.share({
      url: base64data,
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for that - unfortunately I can't check this anymore since I have moved away from React Native to using Flutter.  If this gets more likes I will mark this as the correct answer.